# What is a sane height for a prow in a prow front home?

Tags: design

I'm working on designing plans for my new house, and would like to have a prow front that faces the mountain to capitalize on the view.

I only need about 21' inside for the second story, but because there is a second story and the prow needs to stick up much higher at a sharp angle in order for the house to not look stupid from the outside, I'm getting prow heights in the 40' - 50' range. While it has the right visual proportions, I'm concerned that that is way too high. I've been unable to find any plans for pro front homes online that have dimensions.

**Does anyone know what a practical range of heights is for the prow part of the wall?**

Comment: There are no "building code" requirements addressing sanity.

Comment: Edited to use the word `practical` instead of `sane`. This is about good design (do you need to rent a Genie lift to change a light bulb?), not building code.